# Get the date when two users became friends in php

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery, facebook-friends

It's possible to get the date when two users first interacted on Facebook? For example: in a comment, photo tags, wall post, etc. I need this for a FB app since isn't possible to get the date when two users became friends.

Any idea of I can get this done?

I'm thinking in merging a lot of fql queries but don't figured how to do this yet. If I want this for all my friends, isn't gonna be too slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible now to extract dates from which you became friends with another user on Facebook. Try it via the API Explorer Tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=UID%2Fposts%3Flimit%3D25%26until%3D1342599743

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately it is not possible with the API for existing friendships.

But you should be able to use the Real-time updates (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime) to be notified when they become friends with someone.  Currently the documentation say they support the friends user connection.